Need help determining my salary. Moving abroad
colleagues,
Yesterday I had an interview for an IT job. It was for embedded C programmer position with a relocation to Lithuania. I'd been asked about salary, and replied some digits. And then we touched these salary taxes topic and it went down on me that I'm completely a new bee for this topic to discuss on. The interviewers even changed their facial expressions, maybe mimicking the americans in some way ;) Sorry, but we slavs is indeed slow with supporting our speech with a face expressions.
So, I understood that I do not know taxes, prices, accommodation, government in/outs to name an adequate salary. I have a place to live and know surroundings in my country, but the price tag that I'd told to the interviewers was far below what I will need to barely survive in another country.
The questions
I have hard time to determine a money tag for the relocation, is it OK for me to just ask the other side to name their budget?
What is a general strategy to price my salary for the relocation? I'm moving for the first time, so really need advice.
I'm a overcautious person to do some serious moves. Moving from a zone of comfort takes away all known backup plans, that I could had relied on. So, after move, It is good to have some kind of an additional money support to make me feel safe. Is it OK argument to put some more digits on my price tag?
P.S Sorry about my possible lyrics style issues. I used to ask technical questions on SO. Asking this question, I'm out of scope of my usual topics.

"is it OK for me to just ask the other side to name their budget?" Yes, absolutely! Here is how you should ask: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WChxbBSlWnQ If someone wants to summarize what he says into an answer, please go ahead. It's not my video. As to your other questions, I have no idea. Also, you said you're moving to Lithuania, but you may also want to say where you're moving from. The relocation cost should be a factor in calculating your relocation package.

This question is similar to: How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@StephanBranczyk Hello. I'm moving from Ukraine. The relocation itself is negligible IMHO. I can simply travel by car, or bus. It is accommodation that concerns me. Also, the price ranges may be completely off. What salary I am comfortable with in Ukraine, can be low limit to survive, you know.

@gnat my question is different from what you supplied. no edit is needed.

I suspect "new bee" is a translation error and you meant "newbie".

@keshlam no it is not a translation error. but yes, I did mean a new comer.

Note that companies usually want to pay the prevailing rate for your kind of work at the location you will be working from, which may be much less than what they would pay if you were working in another location. This may or may not affect your ability to save, either possibly or negatively. Run the numbers.

First do your research (which you really SHOULD have done before answering any questions).
A quick google search yields this: https://www.manoalga.lt/en/salaryinfo/information-technology which may be a good starting point.
Next, look at cost of living. Again, Google gives you reasonable data: https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/country_result.jsp?country=Lithuania This one has also a good break down of where the money goes.
For tax and health insurance cost, etc. you can use this https://www.b1.lt/en/atlyginimo-skaiciuokle
I found all of these in less than a minute. Before making a life changing decision, I strongly encourage you to do a few hours of reading up on culture, way of live, cost of living, and all other things that are important to you.

is it OK for me to just ask the other side to name their budget?

It is certainly ok to ask, but typically this is not about a "budget" but the actual cost. This cost depends a lot on your specific situation, which they may not know. A family of 4 with small children and lots of pets and furniture will require way more relocation assistance than a single person that still lives in their parent's basement.

What is a general strategy to price my salary for the relocation? I'm moving for the first time, so really need advice.

Most common is to budget for a short trip maybe a month or 2 before the start date to look at the new place and find housing for your start date. Alternatively you can ask for short term housing for maybe 3 months and than get a permanent flat while you are already working. The other part is what to do with your stuff but that depends on how much stuff you have.

I'm a overcautious person to do some serious moves.

No, you are really not. You should have done some basic research on salaries and cost of living BEFORE doing the first interview. Apparently you jumped in completely blind. You can get a lot of information in less than half an hour. You could have just googled "how to budget for relocation to lithuania" and get more info than I can write up here.

Is it OK argument to put some more digits on my price tag?

If you already have agreed to a salary, than this would be difficult. If you are still negotiating, you can certainly try and see what happens. You already botched this negotiation pretty badly, so you have little to lose here. Do your research figure out, what you really want/need, apologize for you initial misstep and ask what they can do.

Hi, Hilmar. I guess all this remote culture made me less prepared for real life questions. Being a techie person myself, I was preparing to the technical round. The idea to negotiate, not discuss, but negotiate, salary was not even present in my mind at the time. As an excuse to myself I have to say that I am working right now, and we have these power offs in Ukraine. So my schedule is totally unstable and it adds up a nerve and lowers attention to details.

And a note about doing a research. Well, asking a real person with an experience is a best research ;) So yours and other answers are valuable for me. And as a bonus, I trust SO much, try to be of use to community myself. So this notes will stay with me, being always at hand.

@user14063792468. I'm guessing that if you are a "techie" you have no problems whatsoever using Google, ChatGPT, etc to research technical issues or code snippets or API etc. You are in the process of making a life changing decision. You can use the same tools for that as well. How do you know you'll be happy in Lithuania if you don't know anything about Lithuania ? Granted, Ukraine is  in a tough spot right now but you should also try to understand what it means to leave it and what restrictions may apply.

"You are in the process of making a life changing decision. You can use the same tools for that as well." - is it an irony?


So, I understood that I do not know taxes, prices, accommodation, government in/outs to name an adequate salary.

Most places you can look up the cost of living and things like that. It's always best to do this yourself rather than rely on others to do it. But, there's zero harm in asking their salary expectations.
They have a vested interest in retaining a good worker if possible so while they may aim low, they won't be ridiculous about it.
I've moved a couple of times, I haven't worried too much about the start as I'm confident they'll want me to stay, so long as it's livable. So I have gone low to get my foot in and then negotiated my way up later after proving myself. That's sometimes a good route for professionals.

Thank you for your thought. I had a few conversations with a friends, they also have this opinion on getting foot on the ground first.

It's what has worked for me in the long term. It's not a guarantee everything will work out well, but if you're not there, you'll never know. For experienced professionals in high demand industries it's an option worth considering.

It is country-dependent. Because they hired from abroad, most likely to substitute their experts went to better places (West Europe), you had a chance. In any other job, you had not a chance, simply because you are not a lithuanian and you do not talk their language.
Yes, you can ask their budget, question is, what they react. It is like courting a girl. If you are in a foreign place, I think your best bet is let them to say a number or ask yours. If you need to say yours, then say it and give to it, that it is just a number.
Lithuania is a country in the former east block. They are poorer, sometimes much poorer as the western EU members. So the salaries are lower. People out of Europe know this surprisingly rarely, while it is a most basic compass in our life. The guys with whom you talked, were born yet in the Sovietunion. You are lucky, that you do not need to know, wtf was that Sovietunion.
Beside that, people tends to say higher expectations about their salaries, and anonymous questionnaries tend to have higher salaries as the reality. That can make your expectations irreal.
As a newbie, and as a foreigner newbie, I think you had a good result to simply accept what they offer. Probably they said the "newbie" thing because they did not want to say "foreigner newbie".
It was not surely so bad as it has seemed. It looked like a reason for a counter-offer. For example, you might have said X, they wanted to explain that you get only 0.6X because you are a newbie (and they can talk with you only on English). Then you might try to get a reason for them to accept a 0.7X or 0.8X.
At least, that would be the sane way. But things are often very different. For example, in Germany, the company always ask what you want, they mostly do not comment it, and then they either give you an offer or not. There is only very little bargain.
Lithuanians are doing probably the eastern-style, much more open and sane custom, but they are poor. I think, as a beginner embedded C guy, you might earn about 3000 brutto EUR there, pro month.
Yes, I know, we all have friends having friends earning 3453463546342 in a dream job, but these wonderful friends are somehow never us, only someone from which our friend has heard. If you are coming out of the EU and you get a 3000/month offer, I think accept it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
